# Bond Angle of NH3, NCl3 and NBr3

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond

I have read the other answer on chemistrystackexchange regarding the bond angles of $\ce{NH3}$ and $\ce{NCl3}$. The bond angle of $\ce{NCl3}$ is more than $\ce{NH3}$ due to back bonding between p-orbitals and $\ce{N}$ and d-orbitals of $\ce{Cl}$. But recently I came across a question asking for the relation between bond angles of $\ce{NH3}$ and $\ce{NBr3}$. I thought that due to the same reason of back bonding described earlier the bond angle of $\ce{NBr3}$ would be greater than $\ce{NH3}$. But the answer key gave the correct answer as bond angle of $\ce{NH3} > \ce{NBr3}$. Why is it so that the back bonding reason does not work here? Is there any other influencing factor?

And also why is the bond angle of $\ce{PBr3} > \ce{PH3}$ ... which is opposite to the trends shown by corresponding compounds of Nitrogen?

Comment: You should link these answers

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/92323/bond-angles-in-nh3-and-ncl3#:~:text=The%20bond%20angle%20in%20a,H3%3ENF3.

Comment: The second part of question is already answered here :https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/125871/80950

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/65285/why-does-nf3-have-a-smaller-bond-angle-than-nh3#:~:text=NH3%3A%20Here%20N,into%20the%20N%E2%88%92F%20bonds. and this is the first part

Comment: A quick answer one could give to this is due to the large differences in the size of orbitals. We will only get meaningful back bond bonding if the size of orbital involved is close by (i.e: $n$ is nearby). See [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18723/orbital-overlap-and-size-mismatch) as a reference.

Comment: Note, *chemical* information may be advantageously formatted using on ChemSE with [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/). Take moment to familiarize with this. You are encouraged to use it in the body of questions, answers, and comments. Because it is something special not all web browsers understand well, *do not* use it in the title of questions or answers.

Comment: Hey...try to search the questions first... then ask...btw good qsn.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does NF3 have a smaller bond angle than NH3?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/65285/why-does-nf3-have-a-smaller-bond-angle-than-nh3)

Comment: no the above links do not completely answer my question. I have also asked for the reason for bond angle of NBr3< NH3